# Get wwwroot path when in ConfigureServices (aspnetcore)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my aspnetcore app (v2.1) I need to configure a read-only database (entityframework core + SQLite) which is in ~/wwwroot/App_Data/quranx.db

I need to call this code in Startup.ConfigureServices

```
services.AddDbContext<QuranXDataContext>(options => options
    .UseSqlite($"Data Source={databasePath}")
    .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
);
```

But at that point I cannot find a way to get the path to wwwroot. To get that path I need `IHostingEnvironment`, but I am unable to get a reference to that until `Startup.Configure` is called, and that is after `Startup.ConfigureServices` has finished.

How is this done?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's easy enough to access `IHostingEnvironment` in `ConfigureServices` (I've explained how below) but before you read the specifics, take a look at Chris Pratt's warning in the comments about how storing a database in wwwroot is a *very* bad idea.

---

You can take a constructor parameter of type `IHostingEnviroment` in your `Startup` class and capture that as a field, which you can then use in `ConfigureServices`:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Use _env.WebRootPath here.
    }

    // ...
}
```

For ASP.NET Core 3.0+, use `IWebHostEnvironment` instead of `IHostingEnvironment`.

Comment: While this technically answers the question, it should be noted that you should absolutely *not* have a database under `wwwroot`. That is the "public" area of your site, and anything there can be accessed directly on the web. Granted, it would take knowing the exact location of the database file, assuming directory browsing is off, but security by obscurity is not security.

Comment: Thank you! I am rewriting a website from a previous owner who lost interest. Step 1 was to inject the path, step 2 was to check it works in ContentRootPath (it did) and step 3 was to move the name of the database into appsettings.json

Thanks to your help I have just confirmed all 3 steps worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Path.GetFullPath("wwwroot");